# How do I update the server time for Ubuntu Gutsy?

Tags: ubuntu, time

My Ubuntu Gutsy server is a full 2 minutes off of the "official" time.gov time...and appears to slowly be getting more and more off.

How can I get the time back on track and *keep* it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) daemon `apt-get install ntp`.  NTP will be pre-configured with servers from [pool.ntp.org](http://pool.ntp.org).

Comment: +1, this is the correct solution, and frankly, should be the *only* solution.  NTP, once configured correctly, will keep your server's clock-time nice and tidy.